# (Javascript) How do I quickly code multiple types of objects?

Tags: javascript

(The below code represents my current method of creating new bugs.) Is there a faster way to create new bugs? I have to go over each of these functions and copy and paste them. This question is not only to save time, but to attempt to clean the code up a bit.

```
var xBugSpeed = random(1, 3);
var yBugSpeed = 1;
var bugColor = random(15, 100);

var bug = function() {
    this.position = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
    this.velocity = new PVector(xBugSpeed, yBugSpeed);
};
var bug1 = function() {
    this.position = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
    this.velocity = new PVector(xBugSpeed, yBugSpeed);
};

bug.prototype.update = function() {
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
};
bug1.prototype.update = function() {
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
};

bug.prototype.display = function() {

    background(255, 255, 255);
    fill(138, bugColor, bugColor);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, 15, 15);
    ellipse(this.position.x - 20, this.position.y, 30, 15);
    //legbottom
    rect(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y + 4, 5, 10);
    rect(this.position.x - 22, this.position.y + 4, 5, 20);
    rect(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y + 4, 5, 10);
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y + 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 4, this.position.y + 22);
    endShape();
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 25, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 35, this.position.y + 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y + 22);
    endShape();
    //legtop
    rect(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y - 14, 5, 10);
    rect(this.position.x - 22, this.position.y - 23, 5, 20);
    rect(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y - 14, 5, 10);
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y - 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 4, this.position.y - 22);
    endShape();
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 25, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 35, this.position.y - 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y - 22);
    endShape();
};
bug1.prototype.display = function() {
    fill(138, bugColor, bugColor);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, 15, 15);
    ellipse(this.position.x - 20, this.position.y, 30, 15);
    //legbottom
    rect(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y + 4, 5, 10);
    rect(this.position.x - 22, this.position.y + 4, 5, 20);
    rect(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y + 4, 5, 10);
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y + 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 4, this.position.y + 22);
    endShape();
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 25, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y + 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 35, this.position.y + 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y + 22);
    endShape();
    //legtop
    rect(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y - 14, 5, 10);
    rect(this.position.x - 22, this.position.y - 23, 5, 20);
    rect(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y - 14, 5, 10);
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 14, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 9, this.position.y - 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 4, this.position.y - 22);
    endShape();
    beginShape(QUADS);
    vertex(this.position.x - 25, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y - 14);
    vertex(this.position.x - 35, this.position.y - 22);
    vertex(this.position.x - 30, this.position.y - 22);
    endShape();
};

bug.prototype.checkEdges = function() {

  if (this.position.x > width) {
    this.position.x = 0;
  } 
  else if (this.position.x < 0) {
    this.position.x = width;
  }

  if (this.position.y > height) {
    this.position.y = 0;
  } 
  else if (this.position.y < 0) {
    this.position.y = height;
  }
};
bug1.prototype.checkEdges = function() {

  if (this.position.x > width) {
    this.position.x = 0;
  } 
  else if (this.position.x < 0) {
    this.position.x = width;
  }

  if (this.position.y > height) {
    this.position.y = 0;
  } 
  else if (this.position.y < 0) {
    this.position.y = height;
  }
};

var bug = new bug();
var bug1 = new bug1();

draw = function() {

    bug.update();
    bug.checkEdges();
    bug.display();
    bug1.update();
    bug1.checkEdges();
    bug1.display();

};
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between `bug` and `bug1` except `bug`'s display method is making additional call to `background(255, 255, 255);`, this looks like a copy paste code and if it is like this you should only use one declaration of the `bug` and simply make instance of it as `var bug = new bug(); var bug1 = new bug();`

Answer (score 0):

A good practice when you want to create quickly multiple object is to set up a Factory.

Then you'll have a function that you call from a while() that will place your instances in a collection, so you can access them later.

I don't have time to write some code right now, I hope I helped a bit !